# What are you actually doing when you "cancel" out something

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What does "canceling out" mean

Comment: Can you make an example? Typically, you either apply an inverse function to both sides or you appy the rule of annihilation of the product (since you tagged "abstract-algebra").

Comment: The phrase has different meanings in different contexts; as such, your question currently falls into "unclear what you're asking". I'm sure if you would provide a motivating example then this would be a good question.

Comment: In division of algebra I used the word "canceling out" when I multiplied by the reciprocal and my teacher wigged out. I want to be able to understand what it actually is that I'm doing when I have terms disappear?

Comment: @BonnieKelecseny : It would be helpful to rephrase your question: "Is it correct to call this process [insert example here] "cancelling"?  If not, what is a better name?"  Your comment could also be describing replacing division with multiplication by the reciprocal, so it is not clear which thing you are asking about.

Comment: I had to pick from a drop down box so sorry I didn't choose the right word.

Answer (score 1):

You have been asked for a little more context and/or an example.  Prior to that...

It means dividing a factor, typically a common factor, out of two related expressions.  One can cancel a factor from both sides of an equality or inequality.  Examples:  \begin{align}
2 x &= 4 &\implies&& x &= 2 &\text{[cancelling a factor of $2$]} \\
(x^2+1)x &= (x^2+1) &\implies&& x &= 1 &\text{[cancelling a factor of $x^2 + 1$]}
\end{align}
One can cancel a factor from the numerator and denominator of a fraction.  (Note that such a factor must be a factor of the entire numerator and a factor of the entire denominator.) Examples: \begin{align}
    \frac{8}{12} &= \frac{4}{6} = \frac{2}{3} &\text{[cancelling a factor of $2$ each time]}  \\
    \frac{x^2(x+5)}{x+5} &= \frac{x^2}{1} = x^2 &\text{[cancelling a factor of $x+5$]}  \\
\end{align}

In all cases, beware dividing by zero, which in this language is "beware cancelling things that can be zero".  To this end, the last example is dangerous if $x=-5$.  In that case, we have $\frac{x^2 \cdot 0}{0}$, which is undefined, not $x^2$.  If we knew, for instance, $x > 0$, then $x$ is not $-5$ and the cancellation would be safe.  Otherwise, we must handle the case $x=-5$ separately.

Comment: Thank you most most helpful